# About .NET software design philosophy

Tags: .net

Usually, when working with SDKs and Frameworks for Mobile platforms, or open source WebApp Framework (like PHP -> **CakePHP**, **Laravel**, etc), delegation of responsibilities is done by dividing classes into **Model**, **View** and **Controller** (MVC Architecture). The pattern basically is to fill your `Views` (let's say a `TextView` (Android) / `UITextView` (iOS) / `<div>` (HTML from PHP) with your **Model** class data.

It goes something like this: `textView.setText(myModel.getField())`

I'm new to .NET, I'm actually learning it in my University in a software development course, and the first 2 things I noticed is that views are called **controls**. The second thing I noticed is that examples provided uses the **controls** themselves to manage data. Maybe I'm not explaining myself right, so I'm going to give you an example:

In areas I'd separate the **View** from the **Model** and then get a reference to said Model via the **Controller** (lets say with a `Store#getSaleById(int saleID) : Sale`

```
double calculateTotal(List<Sale> mySale) {}
```

They pass directly the **control** as if it served as **View AND Model** and the operation is done by directly getting data from the **control**.

```
double calculateTotal(ListBox listBox) {}
```

So I want to know what's the software design philosophy of .NET, if it is use **controls** directly for operations like the examples I've seen, or if those examples are wrong and **controls** are just views to present data to the user.

Answer (score 3):

The practice you describe is a bad practice by many software developers and isn't prohibited by most frameworks. You can misuse almost every framework by bad coding.

The last years, developers more and more realized that this way of working isn't the way to go. Therefore all new frameworks have a way of working where the MVC like pattern is central.

For Windows Forms development it is all to you, you *can* write your software in a MVC like way, but there are not many tools in the framework to assist you with that.

WPF, the new UI framework from Microsoft supports MVC better by a slightly adapted version of the pattern, called MVVM.

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco: need more thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There are two main architectures: windows forms and mvc. Windows Forms using components and controls. Mvc does not. Both have there uses.

it sounds like mvc may be what you are looking for.

for an intro to windows forms look here: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_intro.asp

for mvc look here: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_intro.asp

for design patterns look here: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx

Comment: Yes yes yes, this is exactly what I need an explanation, could you describe some more Windows Form and MVC please?